# Uploading ML Models into Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, machine-learning, kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to upload ML Model into elasticsearch using the eland script provided in the documentation.

Installed Python, eland & Pytorch but still unable to upload.
python version : Python 3.7.9
Eland version : 8.3.0
torch version : 1.11.0

Below is the script i am executing

```
eland_import_hub_model --url http://localhost:9200/ --hub-model-id openai/clip-vit-large-patch14 --task-type ner --start
```

But facing this error

```
'eland_import_hub_model' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file
```

I am trying to upload any ML Model from Hugging face into elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a matter of just locating the script. I run into the same issue, and when running `pip uninstall eland` I got the location of the script

```
...
    Uninstalling eland-8.7.0:
      Would remove:
        /home/oem/.local/bin/eland_import_hub_model
        /home/oem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eland-8.7.0.dist-info/*
        /home/oem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eland/*
    Proceed (Y/n)? n
```

I think this might occur if you are using a virtual environment.
For windows I found this commit [Make eland_import_hub_model easier to find on Windows.](https://github.com/elastic/eland/commit/4cf92fd9b73af3a059d5e75a8f51df4dae3aa64d)  I am not sure if this could help your case.